# Unable to resolve module 'react-native-screen'

Tags: react-native, navigation, screen

I got this error from React Native on Atom:

> Unable to resolve module 'react-native-screen'

Here are my steps:

1. I ran `npm install --save react-navigation`, and I got the following:

[image: Result of running npm install --save react-navigation]

2. Then I ran `npm install`:

[image: Result of running npm install]

And after, when I run my application, I get an error:

> Unable to resolve "react-native-screens" from "node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\views\StackView\StackViewCard.js"
>
> Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to install 3 more libs `react-native-gesture-handler`, `react-native-reanimated`, and `react-native-screens`.

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

Refs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project

Comment: I had to do: `rm -rf ./node_modules` and `yarn cache clean` as well.

Answer (score 15):

Use below steps, this will work 100%.

1. Install React Navigation

`npm install react-navigation`

2. Install Dependencies

`expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

3. Install React Navigation Stack

`npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view`

4. Start the app and clear cache with npm start -c

Update Imports

```
imports  will  look like this:
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Errors?
If you are still seeing errors and complaints about packages, do the following:

1. `rm -r node_modules`
2. `rm package-lock.json`
3. `expo upgrade`
4. `npm start -c`

Answer (score 4):

If you have downloaded react-navigation then it wont work without its supporting Libs  which are `react-native-gesture-handler ,react-native-reanimated, react-native-screens`

you can download it via yarn or npm  .

```
npm install  react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 1):

If you are using expo for a react-native project then for react-native navigation you need to install below dependencies first.

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

then after installing above dependencies you can install dependencies for different type of navigation like -

1. Bottom tab navigation `npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs`
2. Drawer navigation `npm install @react-navigation/drawer`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following steps :

npm install --save react-navigation

expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-navigation-stack react-native-screens

expo install react-native-safe-area-view react-native-safe-area-context

expo install @react-native-community/masked-view

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your **.eslintrc.js** add these lines:

```js
 settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'node': {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.native.js']
      }
    },
  },
```

In your **.flowconfig** add this:

```
module.file_ext=.native.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading to SDK 39.

Run This Command :

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Thanks.